# Extension submission failing in Technical review

Tags: magento2, error, extensions, submission

While submitting an extension, it failed the Technical review, and the test reports show this error:

Command: Varnish PageCache Test

Output: Cannot update product price.

Response:

```
{\"messages\":{\"error\":[{\"code\":500,\"message\":\"Server internal error. See details in report api\\/1143348353039\"}]}}
```

From the above message, if am not wrong, am supposed to check in **var/report/1273345462353** file but it's their store, their server.  Not sure how to get more details about the bug.

Any inputs on how to debug/solve this will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: have you use productRepository or any other repository somewhere in your Module??

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but could you be more specific? no such repo named productRepository.